# Redirect to previous URL - Lightning Component (Communities)

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, url, redirect

Essentially I am trying to create a back button on my navigation lightning component tab so that when the button is pressed it redirects to the previous url. As it stands I have the follows:

**Component**

```
<button class="button1" onclick="{!c.redirect}"> Back </button>
```

**Controller**

```
redirect: function (){
            var url = window.location.href; 
            var value = url.substr(0,url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            value= value;
            console.log(value);
            window.open(value, '_self');
           return false;

    }
```

I am assuming on the controller i have to add value = value + (previous url), I'm just not sure how to return the previous url, anyone dealt with this issue before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so i figured it out I needed to parse the function like so:

```
    redirect: function (){
            var url = window.location.href; 
            var value = url.substr(0,url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            window.history.back();
            return false;

    }
```

Comment: seems it's just  window.history.back();  not sure if this works on both browser and SF1.